# Error implementing data from one excel file to another

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone assist me plase?
I am no expert at all just trying to fix a code that i'm currently using.
To summarize - got a Holiday tracker and i'm trying to implement it in the file that i'm using on daily basics but it's giving me  Error Run-time 13  type mismatch
Can someone take a look at the code and let me know what exactly is wrong i would greatly appreciate it

The error that is giving me is between **

```
' v1.0 30/10/17 - first release
' v1.1 28/2/18 - compatible with 12h shift planner (no changes)
' v1.2 2/8/18 - accounts for extra columns on the holiday tracker
' v1.3 12/10/18 - compatible with the new holiday tracker
' v1.4 21/11/19 - compatible with rebuilt v2 daily planner
' v1.5 27/12/19 - compatible with 2020 tracker
Sub holidayimport(shift As String)
    Dim StaffList As ListObject
    Set StaffList = Sheets(shift & " Staff").ListObjects(shift)
    'Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\angelovyo\Desktop\Holiday tracker 2023 - Operations.xlsx"
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
            Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\angelovyo\Desktop\Holiday tracker 2023 - Operations.xlsx"
            ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
 
    Dim Tracker As Workbook
    Set Tracker = Workbooks("Holiday tracker 2023 - Operations.xlsx")
     
    Dim list_row, col_payroll, col_holiday, row_tracker, col_tracker, col_trackerpayroll As Integer
    Dim payroll As Integer
    Dim currdate As Double
    Dim holiday As String
     
    col_payroll = 2
    col_holiday = 13
     
    'reset planner column
    For list_row = 1 To StaffList.ListRows.count
        StaffList.DataBodyRange(list_row, col_holiday).Value = ""
    Next list_row
     
    'planner date
    currdate = Sheets("Planner").Cells(4, 17) 'date selection
     
    'day-1 if night shift
    If shift = "Night" Then
        currdate = currdate - 1
    End If
         
    For list_row = 1 To StaffList.ListRows.count
         
        If StaffList.DataBodyRange(list_row, col_payroll) <> "" And IsNumeric(StaffList.DataBodyRange(list_row, col_payroll)) And StaffList.DataBodyRange(list_row, col_payroll) <> 0 Then
            payroll = StaffList.DataBodyRange(list_row, col_payroll)
             
            'find tracker row
            col_trackerpayroll = 1
            col_tracker = Application.Match(currdate, Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Range(Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(4, 1), Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(4, 9999)), 0)
            row_tracker = Application.Match(payroll, Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Range(Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(1, col_trackerpayroll), Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(9999, col_trackerpayroll)), 0)
             
            If Not (IsError(row_tracker)) Then
               ** holiday = Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(row_tracker, col_tracker) **
                 
                If holiday = "" Then
                    holiday = "IN"
                End If
            Else
                holiday = "?"
            End If
             
            StaffList.DataBodyRange(list_row, col_holiday).Value = holiday
        End If
    Next list_row
    
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Workbooks("Fulfilment Training Matrix Omega").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Workbooks("Holiday tracker 2023 - Operations.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

I am expecting to move the data from the Holiday Tracker onto the file i am using

Comment: what are the values of `col_tracker` and `row_tracker`?

Comment: I am really sorry, but i don't know from where i can see them to share them with you. Like i said i barely know anything regarding VBA @Warcupine Is it something in the Holiday Tracker?

Comment: Please place a breakpoint (left click on vertical gray line left of the line) on line `If Not (IsError(row_tracker)) Then`. Then run the macro, ti will pause at the red line, place your mouse over `col_tracker` and `row_tracker` just above and tell us what you see in the appearing tooltip. Most likely one of them is not a number so your ** line is failing as it's trying to address a cell by its cell and row number but is not getting a number.

Answer (score 0):

Changes are marked with `**`

- Validate both `row_tracker` and `col_tracker`, as both are the result of `Application.Match`.
- Ensure `holiday` is a string variable; if necessary, convert the cell value to a string with `CStr`.

```vb
    'find tracker row
    col_trackerpayroll = 1
    col_tracker = Application.Match(currdate, Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Range(Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(4, 1), Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(4, 9999)), 0)
    row_tracker = Application.Match(payroll, Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Range(Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(1, col_trackerpayroll), Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(9999, col_trackerpayroll)), 0)
    
    If Not (IsError(col_tracker) Or IsError(row_tracker)) Then ' **
        holiday = CStr(Tracker.Sheets("HolidayTracker").Cells(row_tracker, col_tracker)) ' **
        
        If holiday = "" Then
            holiday = "IN"
        End If
    Else
        holiday = "?"
    End If
```

Comment: tried it, now the next error is  Else
      **  holiday = "?" **
    End If
I guess it wont work, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: What's the error number and text?